# Replacing function depending on the number of summed elements in its argument

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to replace function

```
f[x+y+z]
```

by

```
g[t]
```

but I do not want to touch

```
f[x+y-z], f[x-y-z], f[x+y+z+u], f[x+y] or f[x].
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility:

```
{f[x], f[x+y], f[x+y+z], f[x+y+z+u]} /. f[a_Plus?(Length[#]==3&)]->g[t]
```

> {f[x], f[x + y], g[t], f[u + x + y + z]}

**Addendum**

With the revised criteria, you could use:

```
length3[a_Plus] := Length[a]==3 && !MemberQ[a, -_]
```

Then:

```
{f[x+y+z], f[x+y-z], f[x-y-z], f[x+y+z+u], f[x+y], f[x]} /. f[_?length3] -> g[t]
```

> {g[t], f[x + y - z], f[x - y - z], f[u + x + y + z], f[x + y], f[x]}

Comment: This replaces also f[x-y-z] by g[t] while I want only f[x+y+z]. I should write that minus makes a difference.

Comment: I have corrected the question adding cases with minus.

Comment: @Jacob What about `(-1 - I) x + y + z`? What kinds of summands will you have?

Comment: I have only sums or differences of varying number of variables. I do not have to consider general expressions.

Comment: @Jacob So, only `f[x+y+z]` gets converted, not `f[x+y+z-u]`?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

```
fs = {f[x + y + z], f[x + y - z], f[x - y - z], f[x + y + z + u], f[x + y] , f[x]};
fs /. Thread[
  Select[fs, (Length[#[[1]]] == 3 && 
       Total[Map[Length, #[[1]] /. Plus -> List]] == 0) &] -> g[t]]
```

> {g[t], f[x + y - z], f[x - y - z], f[u + x + y + z], f[x + y], f[x]}

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = {f[x +  y + z], f[x + y - z], f[x + y + z + u], f[x + y], f[x], h[x + y + z]};

expr /.  f @ HoldPattern[_Symbol + _Symbol + _Symbol] -> g[t]
```

> {g[t], f[x + y - z],  f[u + x + y + z], f[x + y], f[x], 
>        h[x + y + z]}

Also

```
expr /.  f[a_Symbol + b_Symbol + _Symbol] -> g[t]
```

> same result

and

```
expr /. f[_?(Last @ CoefficientArrays @ # == {1, 1, 1} &)] :> g[t]
```

> same result

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the "additive degree" of the variables to be 3; i.e. number of + terms minus number of - terms, this is a quick and dirty solution.

```
degree[expr_Plus] := Replace[expr, _Symbol -> 1, {-1}]

{f[x+y+z], f[x+y-z], f[x-y-z], f[x+y+z+u], f[x+y], f[x], f[x+y+z+u-v]} /. f[expr_Plus] /; 3 == degree[expr] -> g[t] // Print

(* {g[t], f[x + y - z], f[x - y - z], f[u + x + y + z], f[x + y], f[x], g[t]} *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BDoIwEEX3PcVfKqUS4k4DZyC6JA2pWJEElGAxIOHstQVEVvPmv2T@lELdZSlUngqtrzKrpYxlW9VJVDQvjkOAk6wKkU6pi@TclZdnARbCd9Ezf@CE9Le4pR39cBcjsZnYQtbS5sfTXBv25gO8nQlW5d4RewQBVm9xW5zFykgPUZ0/FCEbB72NxnOg6MAw1xr6b41xk6eLN9vyjL0xwNlq/QU)